# UML : Optional Foreign Key

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, uml, entity-relationship

I'm sitting with a little headache about a problem right now.

I have two entities `PAYMENT ORDER` and `ACCOUNT`

```
PAYMENT ORDER
PK - ID
FK - DEBITED ACC
FK - CREDITED ACC


ACCOUNT
PK - ACCOUNTNUMBER
```

I struggle to find the logic when the credited account is not an account from my financial institution. It can not be a foreign key anymore since the account will not be contained within the `ACCOUNT` table.

Have you guys an idea about a workaround?

### EDIT

Question is : Do I have to change the constraint on `CREDITED ACC` to nothing ? Or can I keep it the way it is?

Comment: Is this a question about database design or a question about accounting systems?

Comment: @WalterMitty Database design.

Comment: Why can't you store the account anyway and use another column in the account table to tell you whether it's your financial institution?

Comment: @JimL. I can. That's my question. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What's the remaining question, after my comment, then? Should I just move my comment to an answer?

Comment: @JimL. If possible, it would be cleaner I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you make your `ACCOUNT` table contain more than just an `ACCOUNTNUMBER` column.

If this is just a toy example, add a boolean to indicate whether this account number is internal versus external. If this is going to be an operational system, consider adding a `FINANCIAL_INSTITUTION` table and use its primary key as a foreign key in the `ACCOUNTNUMBER` table.